# Javascript ascii to unicode with this code

Tags: javascript, unicode, ascii

I'm trying to convert texts written in local ascii non-english font to standard unicode. The problem is that we have to use a map file to map each char to which unicode char. Luckily i found a ready open source piece of code within an firefox addon.

It's part of bigger application and i don't understand how I can use it independently. The function this code does is actually convert the text in ascii font to standard unicode.

here is the code:

```
/* ***** BEGIN LICENSE BLOCK ***** 
 *  This file is part of Padma.
 *
 *  Padma is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify
 *  it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
 *  the Free Software Foundation; either version 2 of the License, or
 *  (at your option) any later version.

 *  Padma is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
 *  but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
 *  MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
 *  GNU General Public License for more details.
 *
 *  You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
 *  along with Padma; if not, write to the Free Software
 *  Foundation, Inc., 51 Franklin St, Fifth Floor, Boston, MA  02110-1301  USA
 *
 * ***** END LICENSE BLOCK ***** */

//Panchami Malayalam

function Panchami()
{
}

//The interface every dynamic font encoding should implement
Panchami.maxLookupLen = 2;
Panchami.fontFace     = "Panchami";
Panchami.displayName  = "Panchami";
Panchami.script       = Padma.script_MALAYALAM;

Panchami.lookup = function (str) 
{
    return Panchami.toPadma[str];
}

Panchami.isPrefixSymbol = function (str)
{
    return Panchami.prefixList[str] != null;
}

Panchami.isOverloaded = function (str)
{
    return Panchami.overloadList[str] != null;
}

Panchami.handleTwoPartVowelSigns = function (sign1, sign2)
{
    if ((sign1 == Padma.vowelsn_E && sign2 == Padma.vowelsn_AA) ||
        (sign1 == Padma.vowelsn_AA && sign2 == Padma.vowelsn_E))
        return Padma.vowelsn_O;
    if ((sign1 == Padma.vowelsn_EE && sign2 == Padma.vowelsn_AA) ||
        (sign1 == Padma.vowelsn_AA && sign2 == Padma.vowelsn_EE))
        return Padma.vowelsn_OO;
    return sign1 + sign2;
}

Panchami.isRedundant = function (str)
{
    return Panchami.redundantList[str] != null;
}

//Implementation details start here

//Specials
Panchami.visarga        = "\u00AF";
Panchami.anusvara       = "\u00AC";
Panchami.virama         = "\u00AE"; //Chandrakkala

//Vowels
Panchami.vowel_A        = "\u00C5"; 
Panchami.vowel_AA       = "\u00BF"; 
Panchami.vowel_I        = "\u201A"; 
Panchami.vowel_II       = "\u201A\u00AA";
Panchami.vowel_U        = "\u0192";
Panchami.vowel_UU       = "\u0192\u00AA";
Panchami.vowel_R        = "\u201E";
Panchami.vowel_RR       = "\u201E\u00AA";
Panchami.vowel_E        = "\u2026";
Panchami.vowel_EE       = "\u2020";               
Panchami.vowel_AI       = "\u00A5\u2026";
Panchami.vowel_O        = "\u2021";
Panchami.vowel_OO       = "\u2021\u00A1";
Panchami.vowel_AU       = "\u2021\u00AA";

//Consonants
Panchami.consnt_KA      = "\u02C6";
Panchami.consnt_KHA     = "\u2030";
Panchami.consnt_GA      = "\u0160";
Panchami.consnt_GHA     = "\u2039";
Panchami.consnt_NGA     = "\u0152";

Panchami.consnt_CA      = "\u00DE";
Panchami.consnt_CHA     = "\u00D3"; 
Panchami.consnt_JA      = "\u00D1"; 
Panchami.consnt_JHA     = "\u00CB"; 
Panchami.consnt_NYA     = "\u00C7";

Panchami.consnt_TTA     = "\u00D0";
Panchami.consnt_TTHA    = "\u007E";
Panchami.consnt_DDA     = "\u00B0";
Panchami.consnt_DDHA    = "\u0153";
Panchami.consnt_NNA     = "\u00C3";

Panchami.consnt_TA      = "\u00BB";
Panchami.consnt_THA     = "\u02DC";
Panchami.consnt_DA      = "\u2122";
Panchami.consnt_DHA     = "\u0161";
Panchami.consnt_NA      = "\u203A";

Panchami.consnt_PA      = "\u00B2";
Panchami.consnt_PHA     = "\u00BA";
Panchami.consnt_BA      = "\u00DD";
Panchami.consnt_BHA     = "\u0178";
Panchami.consnt_MA      = "\u00C4";

Panchami.consnt_YA      = "\u00F0";
Panchami.consnt_RA      = "\u00F1";
Panchami.consnt_LA      = "\u00F2";
Panchami.consnt_VA      = "\u00F3";
Panchami.consnt_SHA     = "\u00F4";
Panchami.consnt_SSA     = "\u00F5";
Panchami.consnt_SA      = "\u00F6";

Panchami.consnt_HA      = "\u00F7";
Panchami.consnt_LLA     = "\u00F8";
Panchami.consnt_ZHA     = "\u00F9";
Panchami.consnt_RRA     = "\u00FA";

//Gunintamulu
Panchami.vowelsn_AA     = "\u00A1";
Panchami.vowelsn_I      = "\u00A2";
Panchami.vowelsn_II     = "\u00A3";
Panchami.vowelsn_U      = "\u00A9";
Panchami.vowelsn_UU     = "\u00A8";
Panchami.vowelsn_R      = "\u00A6";
Panchami.vowelsn_RR     = "\u00A6\u00AA";
Panchami.vowelsn_E      = "\u00A5";
Panchami.vowelsn_EE     = "\u00A4";
Panchami.vowelsn_AI     = "\u00A5\u00A5";
//vowelsigns o and O have two separate glyphs, one on left and one on right.
Panchami.vowelsn_AU     = "\u00AA";

//Chillu (5)
Panchami.chillu_ENN     = "\u00FF";
Panchami.chillu_IN      = "\u00FC";
Panchami.chillu_IR      = "\u00FB";
Panchami.chillu_IL      = "\u00FD";
Panchami.chillu_ILL     = "\u00FE";

//vattulu (consonant signs)
Panchami.vattu_GA       = "\u00EA";
Panchami.vattu_TTA      = "\u00E9";
Panchami.vattu_DDA      = "\u00EC";
Panchami.vattu_NNA      = "\u00E5";
Panchami.vattu_TA       = "\u00ED";
Panchami.vattu_DA       = "\u00EF";
Panchami.vattu_DHA      = "\u00E8";
Panchami.vattu_NA       = "\u00EE";
Panchami.vattu_PA       = "\u00E7";
Panchami.vattu_MA       = "\u00E4";
Panchami.vattu_YA       = "\u00AB";
Panchami.vattu_RA       = "\u00B1";
Panchami.vattu_LA       = "\u00EB";
Panchami.vattu_VA       = "\u00A7";
Panchami.vattu_SA       = "\u00E6";

//kooTTaksharangngaL
Panchami.conj_KK        = "\u00B4";
Panchami.conj_KSH       = "\u00BC";
Panchami.conj_NGK       = "\u00C6";  
Panchami.conj_NGNG      = "\u00B9";

Panchami.conj_CC        = "\u00C1";
Panchami.conj_CCH       = "\u00D4";
Panchami.conj_JJ        = "\u00D2";
Panchami.conj_NYC       = "\u00D5";
Panchami.conj_NYNY      = "\u00C8";

Panchami.conj_TTTT      = "\u00B8";
Panchami.conj_NNTT      = "\u00D9";
Panchami.conj_NNDD      = "\u00DF";

Panchami.conj_T_T       = "\u00B7";
Panchami.conj_T_TH      = "\u00CE";
Panchami.conj_TBH       = "\u00CF";
Panchami.conj_TS        = "\u00CC";
Panchami.conj_DD        = "\u00C0";
Panchami.conj_D_DH      = "\u00DA";
Panchami.conj_NT        = "\u00C2";
Panchami.conj_ND        = "\u00B3";
Panchami.conj_NDH       = "\u00DC";
Panchami.conj_N_N       = "\u00C9";
Panchami.conj_NM        = "\u00B5";
Panchami.conj_NRR_1     = "\u00CA"; 
Panchami.conj_NRR_2     = "\u00FC\u00FA"; 

Panchami.conj_PP        = "\u00B6";
Panchami.conj_BB        = "\u00E2";
Panchami.conj_MP        = "\u00D8";
Panchami.conj_MM        = "\u00BD";

Panchami.conj_YY        = "\u00E0";
Panchami.conj_L_L       = "\u00F2\u00EB";
Panchami.conj_VV        = "\u00E1";

Panchami.conj_SHC       = "\u00D6";
Panchami.conj_SHSH      = "\u00DB";
Panchami.conj_SRR       = "\u00CD";

Panchami.conj_HN        = "\u00DB";
Panchami.conj_LLLL      = "\u00BE";

Panchami.conj_RRRR      = "\u00D7"; //ta as in steel

//Digits
Panchami.digit_ZERO     = "\u0030";
Panchami.digit_ONE      = "\u0031";
Panchami.digit_TWO      = "\u0032";
Panchami.digit_THREE    = "\u0033";
Panchami.digit_FOUR     = "\u0034";
Panchami.digit_FIVE     = "\u0035";
Panchami.digit_SIX      = "\u0036";
Panchami.digit_SEVEN    = "\u0037";
Panchami.digit_EIGHT    = "\u0038";
Panchami.digit_NINE     = "\u0039";

//Matches ASCII from 00-0x7D
//Does not match ASCII
Panchami.extra_QTSINGLE_1 = "\u2018";
Panchami.extra_QTSINGLE_2 = "\u2019";
Panchami.extra_QTDOUBLE_1 = "\u201C";
Panchami.extra_QTDOUBLE_2 = "\u201D";
Panchami.extra_HYPHEN     = "\u00AD";

//Dont need
Panchami.misc_UNKNOWN_1  = "\u002D";

Panchami.toPadma = new Object();

Panchami.toPadma[Panchami.anusvara] = Padma.anusvara;
Panchami.toPadma[Panchami.visarga]  = Padma.visarga;
Panchami.toPadma[Panchami.virama]   = Padma.chandrakkala;

Panchami.toPadma[Panchami.vowel_A]  = Padma.vowel_A;
Panchami.toPadma[Panchami.vowel_AA] = Padma.vowel_AA;
Panchami.toPadma[Panchami.vowel_I]  = Padma.vowel_I;
Panchami.toPadma[Panchami.vowel_II] = Padma.vowel_II;
Panchami.toPadma[Panchami.vowel_U]  = Padma.vowel_U;
Panchami.toPadma[Panchami.vowel_UU] = Padma.vowel_UU;
Panchami.toPadma[Panchami.vowel_R]  = Padma.vowel_R;
Panchami.toPadma[Panchami.vowel_RR] = Padma.vowel_RR;
Panchami.toPadma[Panchami.vowel_E]  = Padma.vowel_E;
Panchami.toPadma[Panchami.vowel_EE] = Padma.vowel_EE;
Panchami.toPadma[Panchami.vowel_AI] = Padma.vowel_AI;
Panchami.toPadma[Panchami.vowel_O]  = Padma.vowel_O;
Panchami.toPadma[Panchami.vowel_OO] = Padma.vowel_OO;
Panchami.toPadma[Panchami.vowel_AU] = Padma.vowel_AU;

Panchami.toPadma[Panchami.consnt_KA]  = Padma.consnt_KA;
Panchami.toPadma[Panchami.consnt_KHA] = Padma.consnt_KHA;
Panchami.toPadma[Panchami.consnt_GA]  = Padma.consnt_GA;
Panchami.toPadma[Panchami.consnt_GHA] = Padma.consnt_GHA;
Panchami.toPadma[Panchami.consnt_NGA] = Padma.consnt_NGA;

Panchami.toPadma[Panchami.consnt_CA]  = Padma.consnt_CA;
Panchami.toPadma[Panchami.consnt_CHA] = Padma.consnt_CHA;
Panchami.toPadma[Panchami.consnt_JA]  = Padma.consnt_JA;
Panchami.toPadma[Panchami.consnt_JHA] = Padma.consnt_JHA;
Panchami.toPadma[Panchami.consnt_NYA] = Padma.consnt_NYA;

Panchami.toPadma[Panchami.consnt_TTA]  = Padma.consnt_TTA;
Panchami.toPadma[Panchami.consnt_TTHA] = Padma.consnt_TTHA;
Panchami.toPadma[Panchami.consnt_DDA]  = Padma.consnt_DDA;
Panchami.toPadma[Panchami.consnt_DDHA] = Padma.consnt_DDHA;
Panchami.toPadma[Panchami.consnt_NNA]  = Padma.consnt_NNA;

Panchami.toPadma[Panchami.consnt_TA]  = Padma.consnt_TA;
Panchami.toPadma[Panchami.consnt_THA] = Padma.consnt_THA;
Panchami.toPadma[Panchami.consnt_DA]  = Padma.consnt_DA;
Panchami.toPadma[Panchami.consnt_DHA] = Padma.consnt_DHA;
Panchami.toPadma[Panchami.consnt_NA]  = Padma.consnt_NA;

Panchami.toPadma[Panchami.consnt_PA]  = Padma.consnt_PA;
Panchami.toPadma[Panchami.consnt_PHA] = Padma.consnt_PHA;
Panchami.toPadma[Panchami.consnt_BA]  = Padma.consnt_BA;
Panchami.toPadma[Panchami.consnt_BHA] = Padma.consnt_BHA;
Panchami.toPadma[Panchami.consnt_MA]  = Padma.consnt_MA;

Panchami.toPadma[Panchami.consnt_YA]  = Padma.consnt_YA;
Panchami.toPadma[Panchami.consnt_RA]  = Padma.consnt_RA;
Panchami.toPadma[Panchami.consnt_LA]  = Padma.consnt_LA;
Panchami.toPadma[Panchami.consnt_VA]  = Padma.consnt_VA;
Panchami.toPadma[Panchami.consnt_SHA] = Padma.consnt_SHA;
Panchami.toPadma[Panchami.consnt_SSA] = Padma.consnt_SSA;
Panchami.toPadma[Panchami.consnt_SA]  = Padma.consnt_SA;

Panchami.toPadma[Panchami.consnt_HA] = Padma.consnt_HA;
Panchami.toPadma[Panchami.consnt_LLA] = Padma.consnt_LLA;
Panchami.toPadma[Panchami.consnt_ZHA] = Padma.consnt_ZHA;
Panchami.toPadma[Panchami.consnt_RRA] = Padma.consnt_RRA;

//Gunintamulu
Panchami.toPadma[Panchami.vowelsn_AA] = Padma.vowelsn_AA;
Panchami.toPadma[Panchami.vowelsn_I]  = Padma.vowelsn_I;
Panchami.toPadma[Panchami.vowelsn_II] = Padma.vowelsn_II;
Panchami.toPadma[Panchami.vowelsn_U]  = Padma.vowelsn_U;
Panchami.toPadma[Panchami.vowelsn_UU] = Padma.vowelsn_UU;
Panchami.toPadma[Panchami.vowelsn_R]  = Padma.vowelsn_R;
Panchami.toPadma[Panchami.vowelsn_E]  = Padma.vowelsn_E;
Panchami.toPadma[Panchami.vowelsn_EE] = Padma.vowelsn_EE;
Panchami.toPadma[Panchami.vowelsn_AI] = Padma.vowelsn_AI;
Panchami.toPadma[Panchami.vowelsn_AU] = Padma.vowelsn_AU;

//Chillu
Panchami.toPadma[Panchami.chillu_ENN] = Padma.consnt_NNA + Padma.chillu;
Panchami.toPadma[Panchami.chillu_IN]  = Padma.consnt_NA + Padma.chillu;
Panchami.toPadma[Panchami.chillu_IR]  = Padma.consnt_RA + Padma.chillu;
Panchami.toPadma[Panchami.chillu_IL]  = Padma.consnt_LA + Padma.chillu;
Panchami.toPadma[Panchami.chillu_ILL] = Padma.consnt_LLA + Padma.chillu;

//vattulu
Panchami.toPadma[Panchami.vattu_GA]  = Padma.vattu_GA;
Panchami.toPadma[Panchami.vattu_TTA] = Padma.vattu_TTA;
Panchami.toPadma[Panchami.vattu_DDA] = Padma.vattu_DDA;
Panchami.toPadma[Panchami.vattu_NNA] = Padma.vattu_NNA;
Panchami.toPadma[Panchami.vattu_TA]  = Padma.vattu_TA;
Panchami.toPadma[Panchami.vattu_DA]  = Padma.vattu_DA;
Panchami.toPadma[Panchami.vattu_DHA] = Padma.vattu_DHA;
Panchami.toPadma[Panchami.vattu_NA]  = Padma.vattu_NA;
Panchami.toPadma[Panchami.vattu_PA]  = Padma.vattu_PA;
Panchami.toPadma[Panchami.vattu_MA]  = Padma.vattu_MA;
Panchami.toPadma[Panchami.vattu_YA]  = Padma.vattu_YA;
Panchami.toPadma[Panchami.vattu_RA]  = Padma.vattu_RA;
Panchami.toPadma[Panchami.vattu_LA]  = Padma.vattu_LA;
Panchami.toPadma[Panchami.vattu_VA]  = Padma.vattu_VA;
Panchami.toPadma[Panchami.vattu_SA]  = Padma.vattu_SA;

//kooTTaksharangngaL
Panchami.toPadma[Panchami.conj_KK]   = Padma.consnt_KA +  Padma.vattu_KA;
Panchami.toPadma[Panchami.conj_KSH]  = Padma.consnt_KA +  Padma.vattu_SSA;
Panchami.toPadma[Panchami.conj_NGK]  = Padma.consnt_NGA +  Padma.vattu_KA;
Panchami.toPadma[Panchami.conj_NGNG] = Padma.consnt_NGA +  Padma.vattu_NGA;

Panchami.toPadma[Panchami.conj_CC]   = Padma.consnt_CA +  Padma.vattu_CA;
Panchami.toPadma[Panchami.conj_CCH]  = Padma.consnt_CA +  Padma.vattu_CHA;
Panchami.toPadma[Panchami.conj_JJ]   = Padma.consnt_JA +  Padma.vattu_JA;
Panchami.toPadma[Panchami.conj_NYC]  = Padma.consnt_NYA +  Padma.vattu_CA;
Panchami.toPadma[Panchami.conj_NYNY] = Padma.consnt_NYA +  Padma.vattu_NYA;

Panchami.toPadma[Panchami.conj_TTTT] = Padma.consnt_TTA +  Padma.vattu_TTA;
Panchami.toPadma[Panchami.conj_NNTT] = Padma.consnt_NNA +  Padma.vattu_TTA;
Panchami.toPadma[Panchami.conj_NNDD] = Padma.consnt_NNA +  Padma.vattu_DDA;

Panchami.toPadma[Panchami.conj_T_T]  = Padma.consnt_TA +  Padma.vattu_TA;
Panchami.toPadma[Panchami.conj_T_TH] = Padma.consnt_TA +  Padma.vattu_THA;
Panchami.toPadma[Panchami.conj_TBH]  = Padma.consnt_TA +  Padma.vattu_BHA;
Panchami.toPadma[Panchami.conj_TS]   = Padma.consnt_TA +  Padma.vattu_SA;
Panchami.toPadma[Panchami.conj_DD]   = Padma.consnt_DA +  Padma.vattu_DA;
Panchami.toPadma[Panchami.conj_D_DH] = Padma.consnt_DA +  Padma.vattu_DHA;
Panchami.toPadma[Panchami.conj_NT]   = Padma.consnt_NA +  Padma.vattu_TA;
Panchami.toPadma[Panchami.conj_ND]   = Padma.consnt_NA +  Padma.vattu_DA;
Panchami.toPadma[Panchami.conj_NDH]  = Padma.consnt_NA +  Padma.vattu_DHA;
Panchami.toPadma[Panchami.conj_N_N]  = Padma.consnt_NA +  Padma.vattu_NA;
Panchami.toPadma[Panchami.conj_NM]   = Padma.consnt_NA +  Padma.vattu_MA;
Panchami.toPadma[Panchami.conj_NRR_1] = Padma.consnt_NA +  Padma.vattu_RRA;
Panchami.toPadma[Panchami.conj_NRR_2] = Padma.consnt_NA +  Padma.vattu_RRA;

Panchami.toPadma[Panchami.conj_PP]  = Padma.consnt_PA +  Padma.vattu_PA;
Panchami.toPadma[Panchami.conj_BB]  = Padma.consnt_BA +  Padma.vattu_BA;
Panchami.toPadma[Panchami.conj_MP]  = Padma.consnt_MA +  Padma.vattu_PA;
Panchami.toPadma[Panchami.conj_MM]  = Padma.consnt_MA +  Padma.vattu_MA;

Panchami.toPadma[Panchami.conj_YY]  = Padma.consnt_YA +  Padma.vattu_YA;
Panchami.toPadma[Panchami.conj_L_L] = Padma.consnt_LA +  Padma.vattu_LA;
Panchami.toPadma[Panchami.conj_VV]  = Padma.consnt_VA +  Padma.vattu_VA;

Panchami.toPadma[Panchami.conj_SHC]  = Padma.consnt_SHA +  Padma.vattu_CA;
Panchami.toPadma[Panchami.conj_SHSH] = Padma.consnt_SHA +  Padma.vattu_SHA;
Panchami.toPadma[Panchami.conj_SRR]  = Padma.consnt_SA +  Padma.vattu_RRA;

Panchami.toPadma[Panchami.conj_HN]   = Padma.consnt_HA +  Padma.vattu_NA;
Panchami.toPadma[Panchami.conj_LLLL] = Padma.consnt_LLA +  Padma.vattu_LLA;

Panchami.toPadma[Panchami.conj_RRRR] = Padma.consnt_RRA +  Padma.vattu_RRA;

//Miscellaneous(where it doesn't match ASCII representation)
Panchami.toPadma[Panchami.extra_QTSINGLE_1] = "'";
Panchami.toPadma[Panchami.extra_QTSINGLE_2] = "'";
Panchami.toPadma[Panchami.extra_QTDOUBLE_1] = '"';
Panchami.toPadma[Panchami.extra_QTDOUBLE_2] = '"';
Panchami.toPadma[Panchami.extra_HYPHEN]   = '-';

Panchami.redundantList = new Object();
Panchami.redundantList[Panchami.misc_UNKNOWN_1] = true;

Panchami.prefixList = new Object();
Panchami.prefixList[Panchami.vattu_RA]   = true;
Panchami.prefixList[Panchami.vowelsn_E]  = true;
Panchami.prefixList[Panchami.vowelsn_EE] = true;
Panchami.prefixList[Panchami.vowelsn_AI] = true;

Panchami.overloadList = new Object();
Panchami.overloadList[Panchami.vowel_I]        = true;
Panchami.overloadList[Panchami.vowel_U]        = true;
Panchami.overloadList[Panchami.vowel_R]        = true;
Panchami.overloadList[Panchami.vowel_O]        = true;
Panchami.overloadList[Panchami.consnt_LA]      = true;
Panchami.overloadList[Panchami.chillu_IN]      = true;
Panchami.overloadList[Panchami.vowelsn_R]      = true;
Panchami.overloadList[Panchami.vowelsn_E]      = true;
```

I want to make this work. Convert text in a text in put and put the result in another input.

**UPDATE:** Sorry for not explaining properly. The language is Indian. Before the characters where not standardised until UTF8(Guess I'm correct). So people use to make fonts however they want. [This is the font](http://vijipinarayi.info/support/fonts/Panchami.ttf) in which the text is now. Now after the advent of unicode many standard fonts are there which renders properly on web and used by new websites and all. [Here is the list of some unicode fonts](http://www.wazu.jp/gallery/Fonts_Malayalam.html) There is already some script written in python for converting this. Here is the [python code](http://snipt.org/kpmG/) 
The javascript code I pasted is from an addon in firefox that converts the webpages in the font which I want to convert from to the standard unicode one. The addon is big and does for many some 30+ languages. I only want for this so took this file. But can figure out how I can do it. Hope this explanation is gud enuf.

Comment: "ascii non-english" - there is no such beast. It's either ASCII or non-English. And make sure you _understand_ what that GPL text at the top really means, especially if you're developing commercial, proprietary software.

Comment: @paxdiablo what about e.g. pinyin, it's both ascii and non-english, isn't ?

Comment: @pax Well, it could be romanized Japanese, which uses ASCII characters but is not English. ;) True though, @esafwan, what exactly are you trying to do? All strings in Javascript are Unicode, and Unicode is backwards compatible with ASCII, so why the need to convert? ASCII also can't contain non-latin characters. So your questions doesn't make a lot of sense. Can you elaborate?

Comment: i guess then its not ascii.. its a non-unicode font which i want to convert and my application is also GPL.

Comment: I think you're also confusing *fonts* and *characters sets*. A font is something like Helvetica or Arial, which has nothing to do with Unicode or non-Unicode. So, assuming you're talking about **a string encoded in a non-Unicode character set**, where does this string come from? I suppose you're outputting it on the server somehow, and viewed in the browser it turns into gibberish? Then Javascript is *not* the way to fix this. Please explain more about your *actual* problem.

Comment: @mykhal: pinyin is not ASCII as it contains accentuated characters to convey the tons.

Comment: I'm sorry, do you mean to say that, lacking an original Indian language encoding, people just abused existing ASCII code points to create Indian fonts and wrote pages in ASCII targeting a specific *font*? I wasn't aware such atrocities were ever committed, but then the question *does* make more sense. What about [ISCII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indian_Script_Code_for_Information_Interchange), why wasn't that used? Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: Yes...Exactly... It was done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Closing the question as the question is about a local matter which the community has no idea whatsoever.

Answer (score 0):

will this work?

```
var s = "..."; // your input string
var r = ""; // result
for (i in s) {
    r += Panchami.lookup(s[i]);
}
alert(r);
```